# How to import a class that is not inside header file

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, header-files

I am relatively new to c++. So apologies if this q is naive. But I couldn't get an answer so asking it here.

I have an existing .cpp file (one.cpp) which has a class (class A) defined inside it(one.cpp does not have corresponding one.h). Now I want another class (class B) in another file (two.h) to extend class A. But as A is not inside a header, I cannot do #include one.h

I am thinking of creating one.h, but class A is huge, so trying to avoid it.
Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the linker to be able to identify class A in two.h, it would need reference to that class through a header file. As far as I know, there's no way around that.

Keep in mind that you only need to put the function prototypes in the header, not the actual definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can include `one.cpp` in your `two.h` file like this `#include "one.cpp"`. However this is considered bad practice. What you should do is create a header file for your class A.

Keep in mind that you don't have to actually implement the class in the header file.